# I am not able to get the output for the following code and the error is shown in 'sc'. Error shown is "Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed"

Tags: java

I am trying to take input from the keyboard but I am getting errors.

```
 import java.util.*;
        public class FirstClass{
            public static void main(String[] args){
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                String name=sc.next();
                System.out.println(name);
           }


}
```

Comment: It is only a warning. Not an error.

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code in a text editor inside a file called `FirstClass.java`

Compiled your code using `javac FirstClass.java`
Ran it using `java FirstClass`

This takes the cursor to the next line where an input is expected. I entered the string "hey", and your code printed out "hey".

In short, your code is working fine. You need to enter an input after you run your code.

PS: `'sc' is never closed` is a warning and not an error. You should however consider using `try-with-resources` to prevent any resource leaks.